# Software to auto-mark facial points on images

Tags: image-processing, feature-extraction, facial-recognition

I'm not interested in facial recognition per se, but my question is related. Is there a software (commercial, Github etc), which can mark, with color dots, the same reference points on a face (e.g. the outer corners of an eye, the corners of the mouth etc) on a series on photos? It's the same person, the facial expression doesn't change, but the photos are at different angles, different weather conditions etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried mediapipe facemesh, i think you will get all the points which you need for face.
https://github.com/google/mediapipe/wiki/MediaPipe-Face-Mesh

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I need.